# What is the general term for "greater than or equal to" and "less than or equal to"?

Tags: mathematics

We call this *equation*:

- `A = B`

We call this *inequality*:

- `A > B`
- `A < B`

What do we call this:

- `A ≥ B`
- `A ≤ B`

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first is "strict inequality" - greater than or less than.

The second is just called "inequality" - greater than or equal to or less than or equal to.

The reason being that A > B implies that A must be greater than B: there is no alternative to this statement. It is strict.

However, A >= B means that A could be greater than B, but it could also be equal. It is less strict, but we just call it "inequality", not unstrict inequality.

Comment: OK, so I was wrong thinking that the second one (with `>` and `<`) was called *inequality*...?

Comment: @barakmanos Not at all: > and < are still inequalities, but if you want to differentiate them from ≥ and ≤, you would call them "strict inequalities". Calling them inequalities on their own is still fine. :)

Comment: @donaldacmartin. I think you are using "first" to mean "second" and "second" to mean "third".

Comment: All inequalities are not created equal.

Comment: @HotLicks All inequalities are created equal, sum is just more equal than others...

Comment: For the third case, if I call it an equation, is that wrong?

Comment: Why greater or equal implies that A is less than B?